# CSS animation won't work on iPad chrome or Safari

Tags: css, ipad

I have a simple CSS animation which runs fine on desktop but doesn't seem to work on iPad. I have tried both Chrome and Safari.

Here's the code:

```
.scroll-down img {
    -webkit-animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite running myscroll;
    -moz-animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite running myscroll;
    animation: 3s ease 0s normal none infinite running myscroll;
}

@-webkit-keyframes myscroll {
    0% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(101px);
        transform: translateY(101px);
    }
}
```

Do I have some type of syntax error?

Answer (score 1):

always add the generic - not browser specific version of css when also using the browser one  ex.

```
@-webkit-keyframes myscroll {
    0% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(101px);
        transform: translateY(101px);
    }
}

@keyframes myscroll {
    0% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 1
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(101px);
        transform: translateY(101px);
    }
}
```

Comment: just fyi - there was a typo at first , if you had tried that code before I fixed it , try it again

Comment: thanks for your answer, some reason its still not working even with the new generic `@keyframes` css. It might be my ipad

Comment: I always recommend for ipad only bugs to simply take the ipad and throw it in the garbage ... that usually solves the bug

Comment: I agree with you 100% but unfortunately I cant do that in this case lol

Comment: i figured it out incase you were wondering ill update the answer

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution. Apparently iPad doesnt like shorthand so I had to do this:

```
-webkit-animation-name: myscroll;
-webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;

animation-name: myscroll;
animation-duration: 3s;
animation-delay: 0s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
animation-timing-function: ease;
animation-direction: normal;
animation-fill-mode: none;
animation-play-state: running;
```